# Angular folder structure with nodejs and jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I've been trying to figure out a folder structure that will stay effective when my project has grown, and I've found a few resources ([this](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-growth-structure/) for example), but I don't know how I should implement this folder structure and the more I try to read about it, the more confused I get.

Right now I'm basically using the structure that express generated for me with a few small modifications, like this:

[image: 2]]

All javascript files are in src/js/*, all scss files in src/scss/*, and all jade files in views/

Grunt concats all the js files into public/js/app.js and compiles all the scss-files to css and to public/css/*. Both destinations are statically served. However, the part I don't understand is how this is supposed to work for the views. Right now, grunt doesn't touch them and they're always located in views/ where node finds them and renders them.

This works well for sorting by type, but I'm really confused about how I'd structure it by feature instead. There is probably something wrong already, but I don't know what.

Also, should I separate the server code and client code more? If so, how? Can someone provide an example of what it could look like?

Sorry if this post was confusing, I couldn't think of any better way to formulate it.

Comment: lots of seed apps you can look at to see how others manage structure. Majority will keep features together rather than component types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after reading a lot and trying out Yeoman, everything makes more sense to me. I was still relying on jade rendering from nodejs and I only served css/js/images statically, which made everything more complicated. I've now rewritten it and ditched Jade (although I have to say that writing Jade is 50 times nicer than html) and I'm serving everything statically.

In case anyone is in my earlier situation, try out Yeoman generator-angular to see how it sets up everything.

Comment: could you provide more details? Just having problems with dependency management. I'm developing backend and frontend in one application, server by node. Any best practises for it?

Comment: I can't say I remember this problem problem very well now, and I'm probably not the best person to ask for best practices. If you're having trouble with structuring, I'd suggest you look up other projects, or generate a clean one through for example Yeoman to see how it's structured. Also, I'd avoid using template languages if you're intending to make something like a single page app (which I was).

Comment: Yeoman and all other projects as I saw them didn't combine frontend app and backend app within one project :/